# Custom taxonomy archive page not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

I have a custom post type, `course` with an associated custom taxonomy `curriculum-area`. On the permalink `domain.com/course/`, a list of all courses is shown as expected. However, on the permalink `domain.com/curriculum-area/equality`, it shows the home page. (The home page is a static page). I would like it to, instead, show an archive of all `courses` in the specified `curriculum-area`: `equality`. Also, if I have a `front-page.php`, this archive page also uses the template from `front-page.php`.

How can I get the `archive.php` template to be applied to this custom taxonomy?

```
// functions.php:

<?php

// add thumbnail support
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 

// add custom post type 'Course'
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_course' );

function register_cpt_course() {

    // custom taxonomy - curriculum area
    $args_curriculum_area_taxonomy = array(
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels'                => array(
            'name' => 'Curriculum Areas',
            'singular_name' => 'Curriculum Area'
        ),
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'Curriculum Area', 'course', $args_curriculum_area_taxonomy );

    // custom post type - course
    $cpt_course_args = array( 
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Courses',
            'singular_name' => 'course'
        ),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'The place to display courses',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'curriculum_area' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,

        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'course',
            'with_front' => true
        ),
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'course', $cpt_course_args );

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your permalink as given is `domain.com/curriculum-area/equality` but you registered your taxonomy as `Curriculum Area`.

For `domain.com/curriculum-area/equality` to work, change `Curriculum Area` in:

```
register_taxonomy( 'Curriculum Area', 'course', $args_curriculum_area_taxonomy );
```

to be:

```
register_taxonomy( 'curriculum-area', 'course', $args_curriculum_area_taxonomy );
```

Also change this line `'taxonomies' => array( 'curriculum_area' ),` to `'taxonomies' => array( 'curriculum-area' ),`

I forgot to say, remember to flush your permalinks after these changes! (By going to the Permalinks settings page and just press Save).

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on your template hierarchy and not the code you showed. `archive.php` is the fallback template for *date, taxonomy, tag, author, category and ctp archive* pages. So it should be rendering your archive taxonomy page.

Look at the code in your `archive.php`  and see what it is doing, for example, it could be loading a specific loop or including another file which does the loop. You can revert to one of the default themes to narrow down the problem.

It's usually a good idea is to specify a specific template for `curriculum-area` by creating a page like `taxonomy-curriculum-area.php` and if you want you can even do `taxonomy-equality.php`.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Comment: I have looked at the Template Hierarchy in depth. I only have `front-page.php`, `index.php`, `archive.php` and `functions.php` in this theme so far. The fact this issue persists with the WP default themes leads me to believe it's code related.