# CPT Taxonomy As Archive Page – Error 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I have a CPT called `Clubs`. To 'categorise' posts depending on if clubs are in the same league or cup competition (or neither), I also have a custom taxonomy called `Opposition`.

To show which clubs are in *either* the same competition, I am trying to create a page that functions like an Archive page where these specific `Clubs` posts are displayed: `/clubs/opposition/`

To do this, I've created a `taxonomy-opposition.php` template file and edited the `functions.php` file with the following:

```
// Clubs Post Type
function clubs_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Clubs',
        'singular_name' => 'Club',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Club',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Club',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Club',
        'new_item' => 'New Club',
        'all_items' => 'All Clubs',
        'view_item' => 'View Club',
        'search_items' => 'Search Clubs',
        'not_found' =>  'No Clubs Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Clubs found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Clubs',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'clubs', 'opposition' ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'clubs',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-shield',
        'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'custom-fields',
        'comments',
        'revisions',                
        'thumbnail',
        'author',
        'page-attributes'
        )
    );
    register_post_type( 'clubs', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'clubs_init' );

// Opposition Taxonomy
function opposition_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'search_items'      => 'Search Opposition',
        'menu_name'         => 'Opposition'
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'opposition', 'clubs', 
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'clubs',
        'with_front' => false
    ),  
) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'opposition_taxonomy' );
```

The result when I try to access `/clubs/opposition`, though, is an Error 404. The thing baffling me is that I've done something similar for my `Players` CPT, creating a custom `Squad` taxonomy page that does display. And I've followed exactly the same steps in trying to create an `Opposition` page.

(I have flushed the permalinks)

I've referred to existing questions, but so far haven't found the solution:

- [Custom taxonomy archive page not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135660/custom-taxonomy-archive-page-not-working)
- [Custom taxonomy template not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163888/custom-taxonomy-template-not-working)
- [custom taxonomy - Template not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292473/custom-taxonomy-template-not-working)
- [Taxonomy page returns 404 page not found](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/314667/taxonomy-page-returns-404-page-not-found)

Comment: There's nothing for WordPress to display on `/clubs/opposition`. WordPress only lists posts on archives, and `/clubs/opposition` isn't specific enough to list any posts. You need to create Opposition terms, and then you can list posts with those terms at `/clubs/opposition/term-name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same slug `clubs` to register your custom post type and in `rewrite` when you register `opposition` taxonomy.

Change `rewrite` parameter in `register_taxonomy()`

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'clubs/opposition',
    'with_front' => false
),
```

The recognizable address will be `clubs/opposition/{some-term-name}` and will display posts from custom category.

However, the `clubs/opposition` address will still not work without additional code.

Comment: That explains it! Issue now solved @nmr (and @jacob-peattie)